# updating two instance variables at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application with a `User.rb`,  `Question.rb` and an `Answer.rb` model. Predictable relationships are defined between each of these models. A user `has_many` questions, a user also `has_many` answers. A question `has_many` answers too.

I'm trying to give the question-asker the option to select an answer as the '`best answer`'. I therefore created a 'bestAnswer' controller action in the Answers controller. In this controller action, I wish to store the id for the best answer in the `@question`, and also indicate that the particular `@answer` was selected as best answer. Therefore, I tried to `update_attributes` for both the `@question` and `@answer` at the same time

```
if @question.update_attributes(:accepted_answer_id => @answer.id) && @answer.update_attributes(:accepted => true)
```

Full method.

```
 def bestanswer


    @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])     
         if @question.update_attributes(:accepted_answer_id => @answer.id) && @answer.update_attributes(:accepted => true)
             redirect_to @question, notice: 'You have accepted as best answer' 
         else
             redirect_to @question, notice: 'There was a problem marking this as best answer. Please try again.' 
         end
 end
```

This works, but I'm  also aware that Rails supports transactions. Being inexperienced, I'm not sure if I should be doing things the way I did above, or try to do a transaction, or something else. If you think I should do a transaction, how would you write it? I'm a bit confused because I think the transaction should be done on the model and I'm not sure about using instance variables in the model etc, and which model to write it on.

Update. I implemented the suggestion in the first answer in the following way. It works, but it looks weird to me. Since my OP asked how the transaction should be written, I was hoping someone would clarify how to integrate the transaction into the controller action.

```
            if ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
                      @question.update_attributes! :accepted_answer_id => @answer.id
                      @answer.update_attributes! :accepted => true
                    end
                 redirect_to @question, notice: 'You have accepted as best answer' 
             else
                 redirect_to @question, notice: 'There was a problem marking this as best answer. Please try again.' 
             end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @question.update_attributes! :accepted_answer_id => @answer.id
  @answer.update_attributes! :accepted => true
end
```

I use the `!` here because ActiveRecord will rollback the transaction only if an exception occurs, which the `!` version of `update_attributes` will trigger if something goes wrong.

Also, if you have a `has_one :accepted_answer` relationship set up on your Question model, you should use

```
@question.update_attributes! :accepted_answer => @answer
```

instead of manually setting the ID. Generally it is better to let ActiveRecord manage the IDs.

Comment: Thanks, but can you provide a bit more info. Do I put that transaction directly in the bestanswer action? If so, how do I write the redirects for a successful save, or a failed save? Also, I like this idea of a has_one :accepted_answer, but do I need to do add anything more to the Answer model to make it work? I already do belongs_to :question on the Answer model. Thanks if you can help. I'm a little inexperienced so any detail you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: I got the transaction to work as shown in the update to the OP, but it looks really weird the way I've implemented it. Is that how you'd do it? I really only learn by seeing other people code, and I've never seen one of these used before...

Comment: I am not sure that Rails will return `false` from a transaction. If it does, then I would probably store the result in a variable and then use `if` on that, instead of using `if` on the whole transaction method. You can also rescue from `ActiveRecord::Rollback`, which is thrown whenever a rollback is triggered. So if you catch that exception, you can run the `else` part of your if statement, otherwise, return successfully.